# When does recursive binary search terminate if the sought value is absent

Tags: java, binary-search

I am working with binary search and I know how to write this method in a non recursive way but my professor decided to write it using recursion, and here is his code:

```
public static boolean Bsearch(int A[],int low,int high,int key){
     if(low>high)
          return false;
     int mid=(low+high)/2;

     if(A[mid]==key)
       return true;
     if(A[mid]<key)
       return Bsearch( A, mid+1, A.length, key);
     if(A[mid]>key)
       return Bsearch(A, 0, mid-1, key);

    return false;
}
```

My question is how is it going to return `false` and when will it stop calling the method again and return false actually I am not understanding how it will return `false`. Always we have `A[mid]` bigger than or less than or equal to the key value I am searching for .

Comment: OK, I'll assume you've now finished changing the code.  You need to think about what would happen in this kind of algorithm, if the key you were looking for happened not to be in the array.  Then set up some kind of `if` statement that tests for that condition.

Comment: Did you mean to change `high` to `A.length` on the sixth line?

Comment: Indeed, this code will recurse forever in some circumstances -- e.g. if `key` is less than the smallest element.  So is your task is to figure out why, and fix the code, or what?

Comment: The problem is that the code does not do proper binary search. Intervals are only correct for some corner cases and terminal condition is missing.

Comment: No!  If you edit your code to remove the bug, it makes the entire question meaningless, and useless for any future users of the site.  Please don't do this!

Comment: Anyway, there are two fairly fundamental bugs in THIS version of the question, that weren't in the very first version that you posted, and which are not addressed by either of the two answers that are currently here.  You make it EXTREMELY difficult to help you, when the question is slightly different every time we look at it.  In any case, probably the best thing for you to do is to step through your code with a debugger - in which case you'll be able to see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part will be your abort condition:

```
 if(low>high)
      return false;
```

at the end - if no element has been found - the recursion will be called with low beeing greater than high - and that aborts immediately.

look at the two calls:

```
if(A[mid]<key)
   return Bsearch( A, mid+1, A.length, key);
if(A[mid]>key)
   return Bsearch(A, 0, mid-1, key);
```

if mid+1 is greater than A.length, the call will return false.

if mid-1 is smaller than 0, the call will return false.

Both cases appear if you have reduced the list to one element - then `mid+1` and `mid-1` are always matching the `low > high` condition.

the final "return false" statement will never be hit - it just needs to be there cause the compiler cannot know, that one of the IF-Statements is always true. Could be avoided by using if, else if, else:

```
if(A[mid]==key)
  return true;
else if(A[mid]<key)
  return Bsearch( A, mid+1, A.length, key)
else 
  //this is an implict A[mid]>key
  return Bsearch(A, 0, mid-1, key)

 //return false; //no longer required.
```

---

Edit: Sry, didn't notice: When you go into the next recursion step, you should not start with "0" or run until "A.length" - instead you should stay at "low" or run until "high" - otherwhise you are running the array up and down, up and down, up and down...

Modify the recursive method calls like this, then it should be fine:

```
 if(A[mid]==key)
       return true;
 if(A[mid]<key)
       return Bsearch( A, mid+1, high, key);
 if(A[mid]>key)
       return Bsearch(A, low, mid-1, key);
```

For the indexOutOfBound exception, call your first method with `boolean f= Bsearch(A, 0, A.length -1, 9);` (Note the -1)

Comment: i actually added this part  if(low>high)
      return false; but it is still giving an error if the searched element is not found can you please help?

Comment: when i run this code : 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  int[]A={1,2,3,6,8};
  boolean f= Bsearch(A, 0, A.length, 4);
  System.out.println(f);
   
  

 } it is giving me Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Also when i run this : public static void main(String[] args) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub int[]A={1,2,3,6,8}; boolean f= Bsearch(A, 0, A.length, 9); System.out.println(f); } it gives me: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this will never terminate if the key doesn't exist in the array. There should be a base case that checks for when this happens?

Since this is related to a school problem i'll just give some point questions.

When could this happen? If you have searched all the way to the last possible location that key can exist in, when will happen then? What will be the parameters that will let you, the programmer, know that the key doesn't exist in the array?

HINT: The key thing to look for is a relationship between high and low.

```
public boolean Bsearch(int A[],int low,int high,int key){
 //Should have a if statement check here to see if the condition is hit alerting that the array doesn't contain the key
 int mid=(low+high)/2;
 if(A[mid]==key)
   return true;
 if(A[mid]<key)
   return Bsearch( A, mid+1, A.length, key)
 if(A[mid]>key)
   return Bsearch(A, 0, mid-1, key)

  return false;
}
```

Comment: but it is still giving me an error for example when i run this int[]A={1,2,3,6,8};
  boolean f= Bsearch(A, 0, A.length, 4);
  System.out.println(f); it give me:   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Also when i run this :   public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  int[]A={1,2,3,6,8};
  boolean f= Bsearch(A, 0, A.length, 9);
  System.out.println(f);
   
  

 }  it gives me: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: If the answer doesn't work, you shouldn't accept it.  Otherwise, nobody else will come here to help you.